# Placing variable in implementation in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, static

In the following code segment:

```
@implementation Foo
NSString* bar = @"Some text.";

...

@end
```

Is `bar` a static variable, or is it some kind of class or instance variable?  Specifically, how is it different than doing the following:

```
static NSString* bar = @"Some text.";
@implementation Foo

...

@end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first example, `bar` is a global variable, with global linker visibility to the outside world..

In the second example, `bar` is a static variable, with local-file-only visibility (i.e., the symbol is not visible outside the current compilation unit).

For both examples, their positioning relative to the Objective-C keyword `@implementation` is irrelevant.  They have absolutely nothing to do with an Objective-C class, and operate the same whether in or out of the `@implementation` scope.

Comment: So, just to be clear, they are both static variables.  However, the linker scope of the two variables are different.  This linker scope is determined by the use of the static keyword, correct?

Comment: +1. I didn't notice that one of his examples had static and the other didn't, plus the ninja and all. I thought he just meant "what's the difference between declaring it in the implementation and outside the implementation?"

Comment: @Brett NO.  They are not both static variables.  The first one is a definition of an externally visible variable.  The second one is a static variable, which, by definition, has local-file scope, and does not emit a linker visible symbol.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, all variables defined outside of a method are global by definition. They are the same as global variables in most any language. They are not implicitly static (AFAIK), but can be explicitly made so. <strike>I don't think there's a difference between your two examples, but I may be wrong.</strike> I didn't notice you made the second example explicitly static. The top one is global, the bottom one is global and static (file-wide scope).